# Restarting delayed_job with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm attempting to restart my delayed_job worker like so:

```
  task :restart_dj do
    on roles(:app) do
        execute "RAILS_ENV=production #{File.join(current_path,'bin','delayed_job')} restart"
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, I get this:

```
 DEBUG [64a01587] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/me/rails/dino/releases/20160906142152 /home/me/rails/dino/releases/current
  INFO [64a01587] Finished in 0.177 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [713c695b] Running /usr/bin/env mv /home/me/rails/dino/releases/current /home/me/rails/dino as me@91.16.120.84
 DEBUG [713c695b] Command: /usr/bin/env mv /home/me/rails/dino/releases/current /home/me/rails/dino
  INFO [713c695b] Finished in 0.349 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [7c2e9550] Running RAILS_ENV=production /home/me/rails/dino/current/bin/delayed_job restart as me@91.16.120.84
 DEBUG [7c2e9550] Command: RAILS_ENV=production /home/me/rails/dino/current/bin/delayed_job restart
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]   /home/me/rails/dino/releases/20160906142152/config/boot.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]   :
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]   undefined local variable or method `__dir__' for main:Object
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]    (
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]   NameError
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]   )
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]       from /home/me/rails/dino/releases/20160906142152/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]       from /home/me/rails/dino/releases/20160906142152/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]       from /home/me/rails/dino/current/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]       from /home/me/rails/dino/current/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 DEBUG [7c2e9550]       from /home/me/rails/dino/current/bin/delayed_job:3:in `<main>'
```

However, I can run `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart` on my production console with no issue.

I'm using Ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: Why not ```execute "RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart"```

Answer (score 2):

You might try the https://github.com/AgileConsultingLLC/capistrano3-delayed-job gem. I personally use it manage starts, stops, and restarts. It also handles cases such as manually killing a stuck process.

Answer (score 0):

The error output is telling you exactly what is wrong: it doesn't understand what `__dir__` means.

```
undefined local variable or method `__dir__' for main:Object
```

If you look further down in your stacktrace, the reason is clear:

```
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

You are running 2.3.1 in Development, but Production is using 1.9. If you are running multiple versions of Ruby in Production, you are not correctly selecting 2.3 in your application code.